# Checkbox to enable and disable input tags

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a checkbox that I want to enable/disable input tags. All of the examples I find use the click event and it works one time, but I would like it to work as a toggle. When I replace toggle with click the checkbox disappears. I'd appreciate an explanation as to why it works this way and what I can add to my code to get it to work as a toggle. Many thanks.

```
Here is my jsFiddle: <http://jsfiddle.net/squirc77/JAafq>
```

Comment: [Bypassing the jsFiddle only check?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it will work over and over:

```
$(':checkbox').click(function(){
    $('input').not(':checkbox').attr('disabled',!this.checked)
});
```

Comment: Ahh ... makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Please try this. It will work.

```
$(':checkbox').click(function(){
    $('input:radio').attr('disabled',!this.checked)
});
```

The problem in your code is you are disabling all input box, which disable your checkbox as well.

Check my jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/supriti/JAafq/11/